# Pause JS function from another function

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can pause the below set of delayed functions from another function? I want to pause everything for 10 seconds by executing another function.

What I need is something like:

```
function pause(){
pause sleepLoop() for 10 seconds
}
```

If it is not possible to pause the below execution, can I kill it?

```
function game() {
sleepLoop();
}

function sleepLoop() {
loop...
setTimeout('gameActions()',5000);
}

function gameActions() {
actions...
sleepLoop();
}
```

Comment: Blocking running JS is not a good idea. Perhaps if you elaborate why you want to we can give you a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the timer in a variable. Then you can stop it with [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout), and restart it after 10 seconds:

```
function game() {
   sleepLoop();
}

var sleepLoopTimeout;

function sleepLoop() {
    gameActions();
    sleepLoopTimeout = setTimeout(sleepLoop,5000);
}

function pause(){
    clearTimeout(sleepLoopTimeout);
    setTimeout(sleepLoop, 10000);
}

function gameActions() {
    // Actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var gameTimeout, sleepTimeout;

function game() {
   gameTimeout = setTimeout(sleepLoop, 10000); //start in 10 seconds
}

function sleepLoop() {
   sleepTimeout = setTimeout(gameActions, 5000); //start in 5 secs
}

function gameActions() {
   sleepLoop();
}

//start it off:
game();
```

Other than the above, I am not sure what you are asking.

---

To kill (clear) the timeouts:

```
clearTimeout(gameTimeout);
clearTimeout(sleepTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var blocked = false;

function loopToBePaused()
{
    if (blocked !== false)
    {
        // will check for blocker every 0.1s
        setTimeout(loopToBePaused, 100);
        return;
    }
    // payload

    // normal loop now, e.g. every 1s:
    setTimeout(loopToBePaused, 1000);
}

// somewhere in code run:
blocked = setTimeout(function() {
    // blocking our loop'ed function for 10s
    blocked = false;
}, 10000);
// this will block our main loop for 10s
```

Comment: Rly? Never noticed. You cannot implement game ticks in other way however. Also, timeouts are to be adjusted for every specified task: somewhere longer, somewhere shorter.

Comment: @Neal I don't think this it the most elegant solution but I don't think it'll run slow. Care to elaborate?